# Best TFS Template for Single Developer

Tags: tfs

I'm setting up a new installation of TFS 2012 Express. I'm pretty much the only developer - someone else occasionally adds requirements and manages major database changes.

I've read up on and tried out the Agile and Scrum templates included with the TFS installation, but I can't seem to get my head around the best template/workflow for a solo developer. I seem to be spending more time managing the task board and whatnot then actually working on code.

Which process template is best for a very small team? How much effort should I expend on maintaining the list of tasks/requirements?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with TFS work item tracking? TFS is a tool that is used to accomplish some goal; begin with the goal you're trying to accomplish and then work backwards.

Comment: I want to manage requirements, tasks and bugs/issues, without creating unnecessary overhead. As far as I understand, either process template can do that (and probably much more), I was wondering if one is clearly more suited to such a small team then another.

Comment: Why? That is a tool focused answer, not a value focused answer. What value do you get out of managing requirements, tasks, and bugs/issues? You could do that with a simple Trello board, or note cards on a wall. This seems adversarial, but I'm not trying to be. Which template to use (if you use one at all) should be driven by what you want to accomplish and how you want to deliver value to your stakeholders. Either is perfectly acceptable for a single developer, depending on situation.

Comment: Thanks for your help, if a simple todo list is all I need, that's all I want to use. The value of using some system, I hope, would be a way that lets the few people involved (currently one other, maybe more in the future) to see progress and let me know if there's any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that I would go with the Scrum template, and only track requirements and bugs, not tasks. Use the built in Kanban board to display the status to anyone that needs to see it. (I choose the Scrum template here because the bug work item type is in the requirements category by default).

Alternatively, if the people who need to be made aware of the status of your work are all collocate with you, a physical Kanban board might serve your needs better. This is the method I usually prefer.

Comment: Thank you particularly for your advice about value-focused requirements in the comments, it helped me to nut out what I actually needed, whereas I had been trying to fit my needs into a particular tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try it out, you can simply create an account here: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/

It's almost a full Team Foundation Server on the cloud, from Microsoft.
It's free up to 5 users and offers source code, work items and a build server.

You can create as many Team Projects as you like in order to test the features in a "safe" environment before adopting them on your own server.